# how do I write an equation in terms of another variable, not in the original equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, this problem is asking me to write the following equation in terms of $a$, where $a = x^2 + 4?$

The equation is as follows:$$(x^2 + 4)^2 + 32 = 12x^2 + 48.$$

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Note that $12x^2+48=12(x^2+4)$

Answer (score 1):

If $a = x^2 + 4$, then $x^2 = a - 4$, so:

$$
  a^2 + 32 = 12 (a - 4) + 48
$$

I'm sure you can take it from here.

Another way is to just expand the square:

$$
x^4 + 8 x^2 + 16 + 32 = 12 x^2 + 48
$$

This is biquadratic, but it is really a quadratic in $x^2$. In reality, the constant terms cancel:

$$
x^4 - 4 x^2 = 0 \\
x^2(x^2 - 4) = 0
$$

Roots are apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a way to make the big equation look like a quadratic trinomial, the form of which will be

$ a^2 +  [(some-number)\times a]  +32 = 0$.

Note : the " some number " will be negative

In order to do this , you'll have to find a way to express the RHS of the equation as a product having variable $ a $ ( that is ($x^2+4$) ) as a factor. ( Notice that $48$ = $4\times$ something... )... and then move the RHS to the left.

Then , solve the quadratic for $a$ ( that is, find the possible values of $a$ that make the equation true, in the same way as you ordinarily solve a quadratic for $x$).

Then , use the value(s) you have found as to $a$ to solve for $x$.